# Where to request a temporary parachain slot on Rococo?

Tags: parachain, rococo, slot

After following [parachain guides](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/rococo/) and setting up a parachain node, we'd like to initiate a temporary slot on rococo testnet for our parachain (`ParaId 2004`).

According to the document, we should request it on [Parachain Technical matrix channel](https://matrix.to/#/#parachain-technical:matrix.parity.io). Since the channel is currently read-only now. Is there any place to request a parachain slot on Rococo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like they have created this process to request rococo slots.

- https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 4):

This does not directly answer your question as I am not sure where to request a slot now that the channel is closed and I am pretty sure you still need to request someone from Parity to initiate the slot lease as it requires `sudo`. However I figured it would be good to link the correct docs/steps for future reference.

Docs for requesting parachain slot on Rococo:
https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/rococo/#request-your-parachain-slot

**Steps mentioned in docs:**

1. In the Polkadot-JS Apps for Rococo, go to Developer -> Extrinsics.
2. Select the account with enough ROC balance that you wish to use to
   submit a transaction with.
3. Select the assignedSlots pallet.
4. Choose the assignTempParachainSlot function.
5. Insert your reserved para ID. Make sure this matches the one you reserved from the previous section!
6. Select Current for the LeasePeriodStart. If the current
   slot is full, you will be assigned the next available slot.
7. Sign and submit the transaction.